# How can I optimize a dot product along a small dimension in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have two `np.ndarray`s

- `a` is an array of shape `(13000, 8, 315000)` and type `uint8`
- `b` is an array of shape `(8,)` and type `float32`

I want to multiply each slice along the second dimension (8) by the corresponding element in `b` and sum along that dimension (i.e. a dot product along the second axis). The result will be of shape `(13000, 315000)`

I have devised two ways of doing this:

- `np.einsum('ijk,j->ik', a, b)`: using `%timeit` it gives `49 s ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- `np.dot(a.transpose(0, 2, 1), b)`: using `%timeit` it gives `1min 8s ± 3.54 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Are there faster alternatives?

### Complementary information

`np.show_config()` returns:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

`a.flags`:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

`b.flags`:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Comment: Have you tried `optimize=True` in [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)?

Comment: Could you rearrange your data to have the dimension of size 8 last? I don't mean just rolling the axis. I mean actually rearranging the data. E.g., `np.rollaxis` followed by `np.array(..., copy=True)` or so.

Comment: A duplicate question yesterday showed that `dot` is notoriously slow for this.  Have you tried `b@a`?  Or `tensordot`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51936253/901925

Comment: `uint8` saves memory, but slows down computations that use compiled code (that works with floats).

Comment: Since `b` is floating, so will the result.

Comment: It would require ~122GB of RAM in `float32`. I'll stick with `uint8` for the moment :-) but thanks for the remark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data and to gain memory efficiency and hence performance -

```
import numexpr as ne

d = {'a0':a[:,0],'b0':b[0],'a1':a[:,1],'b1':b[1],\
     'a2':a[:,2],'b2':b[2],'a3':a[:,3],'b3':b[3],\
     'a4':a[:,4],'b4':b[4],'a5':a[:,5],'b5':b[5],\
     'a6':a[:,6],'b6':b[6],'a7':a[:,7],'b7':b[7]}
eval_str = 'a0*b0 + a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3 + a4*b4 + a5*b5 + a6*b6 + a7*b7'
out = ne.evaluate(eval_str,d)
```

Sample run for timings -

```
In [474]: # Setup with ~10x smaller than posted one, as my system can't handle those
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,8,30000)).astype(np.uint8)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(8).astype(np.float32)

In [478]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,j->ik', a, b)
1 loop, best of 3: 247 ms per loop

# einsum with optimize flag set as True
In [479]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,j->ik', a, b, optimize=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 248 ms per loop

In [480]: d = {'a0':a[:,0],'b0':b[0],'a1':a[:,1],'b1':b[1],\
     ...:      'a2':a[:,2],'b2':b[2],'a3':a[:,3],'b3':b[3],\
     ...:      'a4':a[:,4],'b4':b[4],'a5':a[:,5],'b5':b[5],\
     ...:      'a6':a[:,6],'b6':b[6],'a7':a[:,7],'b7':b[7]}

In [481]: eval_str = 'a0*b0 + a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3 + a4*b4 + a5*b5 + a6*b6 + a7*b7'

In [482]: %timeit ne.evaluate(eval_str,d)
10 loops, best of 3: 94.3 ms per loop
```

**`~2.6x`** improvement there.

A better (less error-prone) and generic way to create the evaluation parts could be like so -

```
d = {'a'+str(i):a[:,i] for i in range(8)}
d.update({'b'+str(i):b[i] for i in range(8)})
eval_str = ' + '.join(['a'+str(i)+'*'+'b'+str(i) for i in range(8)])
```

Comment: Wow! This is really impressive. Gained a factor 7x.